# automatic calling member functions in class

Tags: c++

i am learning c++;recently i came across a code in which the public member functions of the code gets automatically called.i have common idea about constructors,but i think it is not related with that topic;

here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Humidity;
class Temperature
{
private:
    int m_temp;
public:
    Temperature(int temp=0)
    {
        m_temp = temp;
    }
    void seTemperature(int temp)
    {
        m_temp = temp;
    }
    friend void printWeather(const Temperature &temperature,
                             const Humidity &humidity);
};
class Humidity
{
private:
    int m_humidity;
public:
    Humidity(int humidity=0)
    {
        m_humidity = humidity;
    } void seHumidity(int humidity)
    {
        m_humidity = humidity;
    } friend void printWeather(const Temperature &temperature,
                               const Humidity &humidity);
};
void printWeather(const Temperature &temperature, const Humidity &humidity)
{
    std::cout << "The temperature is " << temperature.m_temp <<" and the humidity is " << humidity.m_humidity << '\n';
}
int main()
{
    Humidity hum(10);
    Temperature temp(12);
    printWeather(temp, hum);
    return 0;
}
```

my question is that : why the void seTemperature(int temp) and  seHumidity(int humidity) function gets called? any help will be appreciated .

Comment: What makes you actually think these functions are called? The member variables are set through construction of the class instances.

Comment: These functions will not be called.

Comment: the value 10 and 12 is the output that makes me think the functions are called; what i know about constructors is if i want to use constructors then the function name and class name should be same .. and here i think constructors are used to assign 0 initially to the variables;cant figure out how 10 and 12 got assigned?

Comment: @Rashik _`Humidity hum(10);`_ assigns `10` overtaking the default parameter value definition in the constructor.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ  thanks ,got the point..

Answer (score 0):

The two functions have not bee called in this example. See this: http://cpp.sh/8te7

However, the constructors(`Humidity(int)`, `Temperature(int)` of the two classes have been called and they are doing something and they are doing something similar to the two functions you mentioned(`seHumidity`,`seTemperature`).